# HTML: When to use nested label vs. label for="" id=""?

Tags: html

This is my first post, please forgive me if this has already been posted. I searched around and couldn't find it. I'm currently doing the "The Web Developer BootCamp" by Colt Steele on Udemy and am a complete beginner.

In one of the exercises we have to create a login page (HTML only, no CSS or JS). At one point he uses the nested labels, and at another point he uses the other style (I think it's called labeled control).

Can anyone please explain when one style of syntax should be used over the other? I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You should use the `for="" id=""` method when you can't nest the input inside the label, because you have no other option. There is no other difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the other thread. I've marked this as a duplicate.